# How can I write .htaccess to redirect url to AWS CloudFront?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess

I start to build my first Wordpress webpage and learn to deploy my website on AWS. I want to use S3 to store my media data and use CloudFront to reduce latency, so once somebody visit my website they will fetch data from s3 through CloudFront instead of directly getting data from my EC2 server. The problem is I don’t know how to rewrite the url by changing .htaccess file. I tried several ways but none of them works. Here is my code, can someone tell me how to change it and make it work?

```
# This is code I write to rewrite URL to CloudFront domain
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://(my cloudfront url).cloudfront.net/$1 [R=301,NC]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue? Do you mind sharing some outcome? I am having the similar issue. Thx

Comment: Here is a link to this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/152343/using-htaccess-to-serve-files-from-amazon-s3-cloudfront) with answer!